# How to return text + icon from a function in React

Tags: reactjs

I have written a function in Reactjs and I want to return text with an icon if a certain condition meets. Here is how I wrote it

```
if (actionNeeded) {
  return abbreviation + <i className={'fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-fw'} />;
 }
```

This returns `text [object Object]` instead of `text (icon)`. How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return a JSX element to have your `<i>` rendered.

In you current case, it will see that `abbreviation` is a string and will concatenate your `<i>`as such, giving you the result of an `Object.toString()`.

You can use React.Fragment to do so:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        {abbreviation} <i className="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-fw" />
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: I think that the icon tag should be like `<i class='...'></i>`

Comment: That was my mistake. For some reason when I copied it from my code it removed the quotes from the className. It is updated now but this was not the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Font Awesome's npm packages for React. The benefit of doing it this way is that only the icons that you actually use will be added to the build.

**Installation**

```
npm i --save \
@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core \
@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons \
@fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

**main.js**

```
import {faExclamationCircle, faFw} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {library} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

library.add(faExclamationCircle, faFw);
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**component.js**

```
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
...
if (actionNeeded) {
    return (
        <>
            {abbreviation} <FontAwesomeIcon icon="exclamation-circle" />
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to answer this.

But something that worked for me:

**Installation**

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Import in INdex.js

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
```

component.js

```
 return (
            <div className="errorDiv">
                {showError &&
                <React.Fragment>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} />
                    <span> </span>
                    {error}
                </React.Fragment>

                }
            </div>
        );
```